# Get the last X minutes log and search for a string in a file

Tags: bash, date, unix, sed, grep

I trying to get the last x minutes logs in my log file and then search if an exception is present in those logs

Currently if I have fixed minute interval and a fixed string I am able to achive and obtain the result in the following manned

```
sed -n "/^$(date --date='10 minutes ago' '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')/,\$p" filename| grep m1 'ErrorCode="javax.naming.NameNotFoundException"'
```

My logs look like

```
    2017-04-19 10:01:35,047 529025829 ERROR [server.YCPSchedulableTrigger] 
(Timer-0:) Exception sending message... 
    2017-04-19 10:01:35,048 529025830 ERROR [server.YCPSchedulableTrigger] 
(Timer-0:) [1492596095048]Error_description_not_available 2017-04-19 10:01:35,049 529025831 ERRORDTL [server.YCPSchedulableTrigger] (Timer-0:) 
[1492596095048]<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <Errors>

        <Error ErrorCode="javax.naming.NameNotFoundException"

            ErrorDescription="Error_description_not_available" ErrorRelatedMoreInfo="">
```

My problem is that the string and the duration is passed on as a parameter to the bash script and when I run

```
 sed -n "/^$(date --date='$logTracebackInterval minutes ago' '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')/,\$p" $file| grep -m1 "'$searchString'"
```

I get an error

```
invalid date `$logTracebackInterval minutes ago'
```

Which I truely understand since `$logTracebackInterval`  is in single quotes and not resolve

I have also tried

```
sed -n `/^date --date='$logTracebackInterval minutes ago' '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'/`,\$p $file| grep -m1 "'$searchString'"
```

which doesnt give me any error but also doesn't give me any result

Any help is really appreciated

Comment: If it doesn't have to be a one-liner, you can avoid complicated quoting by doing it in two lines: `datestart=$(date --date="$logTracebackInterval minutes ago" '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')` followed by `sed -n "/^${datestart}/,\$p"`

Comment: @MarkPlotnik , I understand it's a problem with resolving variable, but is it possible to do so in one line that would be best

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variable substitution is suppressed by single quotes. For example:

```
five=5
echo $(date -d '$five minutes ago')
date: invalid date ‘$five minutes ago’
```

You need to say something like:

```
echo $(date -d "$five minutes ago")
```

Specifically, something like:

```
sed "/$(date -d "$five minutes ago")/p" file
```

Comment: I knew that variable is not rsolved within a single quotes, just didn't try `"` within `"` as I felt that the center part won't be execute properly then, I knew it was easy. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

sed could grep (m1) your result also

```
sed "/^$(date --date="10 minutes ago" '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')/,\$p!d" -e ' /ErrorCode="javax.naming.NameNotFoundException"/!d" -e 'q' "${file}
```

BUT this will failed if there is no line with your exact date

awk is a better tool in this case

```
awk -v T="$(date --date="10 minutes ago" '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')" '
   # catch date and hour (could be better but enough for the need)
   BEGIN { split( T, aT);d=aT[1];h=aT[2]}

   # hoppefully, date format is string comparable order in your log
   # ignore earlier line
   $1$2 < d t { next }

   # exit after first occurance print
   /ErrorCode="javax.naming.NameNotFoundException"/ { print; exit }
   ' "${file}"
```

one-liner version

```
awk -v T="$(date --date="10 minutes ago" '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')" 'BEGIN{split(T,aT);d=aT[1];h=aT[2]};$1$2<d t{next};/ErrorCode="javax.naming.NameNotFoundException"/{print;exit}' "${file}"
```

Comment: The sed command that I am using is giving me logs for the past 10 min interval, not for the exact minute. Anyways I just wanted a way to resolve the variable because apart from that the command was working fine and the files that I was searching in have been modified in the 10min interval only.